# How to stop all threads as soon as one is finished?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 5 threads (5 instances of one Runnable class) starting approximately at the same time  (using `CyclicBarrier`) and I need to stop them all as soon as one of them finished.

Currently, I have a `static` `volatile` `boolean` field `threadsOver` that I'm setting to true at the end of `doSomething()`, the method that `run()` is calling.

```java
private static final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(5);
private static volatile boolean threadsOver;
```

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        /* waiting for all threads to have been initialised,
           so as to start them at the same time */
        barrier.await();
        doSomething();
    } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```java
public void doSomething() {
    // while something AND if the threads are not over yet
    while (someCondition && !threadsOver) {
         // some lines of code
    }
    // if the threads are not over yet, it means I'm the first one to finish
    if (!threadsOver) {
         // so I'm telling the other threads to stop
         threadsOver = true;
    }
}
```

The problem with that code is that the code in `doSomething()` is executing too fast and as a result, the threads that finish after the first one are already over by the time that the first thread noticed them.

I tried adding some delay in `doSomething()` using `Thread.sleep()`, which reduced the number of threads which finished even after the first one, but there are still some times where 2 or 3 threads will finish execution completely.

How could I make sure that when one thread is finished, all of the others don't execute all the way to the end?

Comment: "The problem with that code is that the code in doSomething() is executing too fast and as a result, the threads that finish after the first one are already over by the time that the first thread noticed them." -- this does not make any sense. Can you please give a better explanation of exactly what the problem is?  In other words: 1. What is the expected result? 2. What happens instead?

Answer (score 1):

> First where I copied code snippets from: https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial .

As you have 5 tasks of which every one can produce the result, I prefer `Callable`, but `Runnable` with a side effect is handled likewise.

The almost simultaneous start, the Future task aspect, and picking the first result can be done by `invokeAny` below:

```
Callable<Integer> callable1 = () -> {
    return 1*2*3*5*7/5;
};

List<Callable<Integer>> callables = List.of(callable1, callable2, ...);

ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5);

Integer results = executorService.invokeAny(callables);
executorService.shutDown();
```

> **`invokeAny()`** assigns a collection of tasks to an `ExecutorService`, causing each to run, and returns the result of a successful execution of one task (if there was a successful execution).

Comment: Isn't `executorService.shutDown()` simply going to tell the executor to reject further incoming tasks? Shouldn't `executorService.shutDownNow()` be used instead?

Comment: I am always uncertain, and check such things out. In this case `invokeAny` should have let all threads end. So the only final thing is to shut down the thread pool itself. But please, `shutDownNow` might just be the right thing to do. _I could have tested this fast, and come with a godly claim carved in stone, But better do it yourself._